# minted error in org-mode

Tags: windows, org-mode

I am using org-mode. when I try to compile a org file into a pdf with minted package enabled, I get a error. for instance,

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{minted}
\author{My name}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

then I got an error as follows

```
! Emergency stop.
<read 3> 

l.24 \author
            {My name}^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on .//memo.log.
```

It looks like the statement next to the \usepackage{minted} statement gets the error like the above example.

FYI, if I compile the org file with pdflatex command directly, I get a pdf file without any problem. If I try to compile it in org-mode (Export to LaTeX As PDF file), I got the error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does the error go away if you put the minted package in before the hyperref package?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. Thanks a lot.